# Extension function override of `equals(Any?): Boolean`

Tags: kotlin

A Java dependency defines some value classes without equals methods. They really should implement it, but they don't.

```
public class OrderBookEntry {

  private String price;
  private String qty;

  public String getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public String getQty() {
    return qty;
  }

  public void setQty(String qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
  }
}
```

I would like to implement equals by extension

```
fun OrderBookEntry.equals(other: Any?): Boolean = 
  EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, other)
```

but I'm given a warning that

> Extension is shadowed by a member. `public open fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean`

and the extension method has no effect.

Can I override the equals behaviour?

Comment: Choose a different name for your extension function? Why use reflection BTW?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm trying to override `equals`. If I choose a different name, how does object equality work? Reflection because it was available. I'll choose something better when it works. Implementation is moot if the method isn't called.

Comment: You can't override anything using an extension function. Extension functions are just static helper methods disguised as member functions. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically

Comment: Ah, OK. That's unfortunate. :( . I'm sure it's done this way for a good reason though. I'll accept a "you can't" answer.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but as a suggestion, if available, you can wrap the Java class in a Kotlin class and define the equals you would have wanted for your Java class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't override a method using an extension function.

```
fun OrderBookEntry.foo(other: Any?): Boolean
```

is equivalent, in Java, to having a static helper method such as

```
public static boolean foo(OrderBookEntry fakeThis, Object other)
```

Extension functions are resolved statically, can't shadow a member method, and must be explicitly imported (when called from another package) in order to be available.